# Scons Glob and Builder - Only building first file in Glob

Tags: python, scons

I have a Builder that looks like this:

```
baseEnv['COMPILEPROPERCOM'] = '$CXX -S -o ${TARGET.file} -c $CPPFLAGS -fPIC $COMPILE_PROPER_PATH $COMPILE_PROPER_DEFINES ${SOURCE.file}'
    compileProperAction = Action('$COMPILEPROPERCOM')
    compileProper_bld = Builder(action=compileProperAction, suffix = '.s_', chdir=1)
```

And I'm calling it in an SConscript like this:

```
    asm = libEnv.cp([Glob('*.c'),Glob('*.cpp')])
```

The issue that I am having is that only the first file in the Glob is being built.  I tried not using a Glob and passing the name of a few files in manually, but again, only one file was built.  So I'm guessing something is wrong with my Builder, but I can't figure it out.  Any thoughts on why when a node list is passed to this builder only a single file is built?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After attacking it a different way thanks to Louis's answer, what ended up working for me was to call the builders like so.

```
instrAsm = []
for a in asm:
    instrAsm += exeEnv.instr(a)
for g in Glob('*.s'):
    instrAsm += exeEnv.instr(g)
```

`asm` contains the nodes from some source files that are being compiled to assembly in a previous step

Answer (score 1):

I would write it like this :

```
import os, glob
for filename in glob('*.c'):
    asm = libEnv.cp(filename, os.path.split(filename)[0] + ".cpp")
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I tried something similar to this but was getting dependency errors, I added what finally worked for me as an answer.